# displaying a listbox using Html.List, and I have a List<User> collection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, listbox

Is a List enumerable?

```
Html.List("mylistbox", Model.UserList);
```

doesnt' seem to be working, where UserList is a List collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the DropDownList helper?

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("Layers", Model.GetLayersOptions("2"))%>
```

Make sure your Model.UserList property is of type `IEnumerable<T>`.  Here's my implementation:

```
    public virtual IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetLayersOptions(string defaultSt)
    {
        var items = new List<SelectListItem>
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "1", Value = "1"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "2", Value = "2"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "12", Value = "12"}
                    };
        Utils.SetSelectedItem(items, defaultSt, () => Layers);
        return items;
    }
```